# if (identical values between 2 array indices) { set data in corresponding spreadsheet }

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Summary of the script: Scrapes basic email information (date sent/received, to, from, subject, email label) and logs this data into spreadsheets. The spreadsheets are named after email labels, all emails that belong to a certain label get their information logged to that corresponding spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet names and Ids are organized in the array of arrays `fileNames` as `[[spreadsheet name, id],[spreadsheet name, id],[etc, etc]]`

Below is some of this array setup.

```
function testFunction(){  

var emailByLabel = ["just", "a", "list", "of", "data"];

 // ** CREATE AN ARRAY OF ARRAYS. 
 // LAYER 1- [LIST OF SPREADSHEETS]
 // LAYER 2- [SPREADSHEET NAME, SPREADSHEET ID]
 var fileNames = [];
 var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("email-data");

 while (folders.hasNext()) {
     var folder = folders.next();
     var files = folder.getFiles();
   while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      fileNames.push([file.getName(), file.getId()]);
   } 
 }
```

It is here that I am trying to "match" spreadsheet names to label names, and "set" data to corresponding spreadsheets when there's a match. Instead what I am getting is all data in all spreadsheets.

```
for(var l=0;l<fileNames.length;l++){
    for(var i=0;i<emailByLabel.length;i++){
      if(emailByLabel[i][1] == fileNames[l][0]){

        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileNames[l][1]).getSheets()[0];
        Logger.log(fileNames[l][0]);
        Logger.log(fileNames[l][1]);

        ss.getRange(2,1,emailByLabel.length,5).setValues(emailByLabel);

      } else {
        Logger.log("MATCH, BROKE!");
        Logger.log(fileNames[l][0]);
        Logger.log(fileNames[l][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried replacing

```
    ss.getRange(2,1,emailByLabel.length,5).setValues(emailByLabel);
```

with

```
    ss.getRange(2,1,emailByLabel[i].length,5).setValues(emailByLabel[i]);
```

but i receive the error `Cannot convert Array to Object[][]`

Full Code with some highlighted, relevant lines of code: http://pastie.org/9793256#96,100,109,117,123-139

Answer (score 0):

`emailByLabel[i]` wont work since it's an one dimension array.

Try with this instead:

```
ss.getRange(2,1,emailByLabel[i].length,5).setValues([emailByLabel[i]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use .indexOf() to do the matching ? [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
for(var l=0;l<fileNames.length;l++){  
  if(emailByLabel.indexOf(fileNames[l][0]) !== -1) {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileNames[l][1]).getSheets()[0];
    Logger.log(fileNames[l][0]);
    Logger.log(fileNames[l][1]);

    ss.getRange(2,1,emailByLabel.length,5).setValues(emailByLabel);

  } else {
    Logger.log("MATCH, BROKE!");
    Logger.log(fileNames[l][0]);
    Logger.log(fileNames[l][1]);
  }
}
}
```